# Booting Linux from scratch off of an external hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, grub

I first posted this on stack overflow and it got closed with the suggestion to post here.

I have finished the building portion of Linux from scratch (Version 10.0) for the first time. I opted to build it off of an external hard drive because I had little room left on the host machine. I am having trouble booting it after following the LFS guide.

the partitions on the hard drive:

sdb1 = bios

sdb2 = boot

sdb3 = root

sdb4 = swap

Here is my grub config currently:

```
# Begin /boot/grub/grub.cfg
set default=0
set timeout=5

insmod ext2
set root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/601dfc72-8481-40d6-bd42-1194dc574feb

menuentry "GNU/Linux, Linux 5.8.3-lfs-10.0" {
      linux   vmlinuz-5.8.3-lfs-10.0 root=/dev/disk/by-label/DESTROOT ro
}
```

the 'set root' option is set to the uuid of the root partition, and the 'root' in the menu entry is by-label to the same root partition. I have nothing pointing to the boot partition and I feel like I should.

I followed the [LFS guide](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter10/grub.html) for this configuration, but swapped out the names like (hd0,2) for what i thought would be more specific.

Here is my current fstab:

```
# Begin /etc/fstab

# file system  mount-point  type     options             dump  fsck
#                                                              order

/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500ace19f9a-part3     /            ext4    defaults            1     1
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500ace19f9a-part4     swap         swap     pri=1               0     0
proc           /proc        proc     nosuid,noexec,nodev 0     0
sysfs          /sys         sysfs    nosuid,noexec,nodev 0     0
devpts         /dev/pts     devpts   gid=5,mode=620      0     0
tmpfs          /run         tmpfs    defaults            0     0
devtmpfs       /dev         devtmpfs mode=0755,nosuid    0     0

# End /etc/fstab
```

I have tried to use supergrub2disk to boot, and i can get to grub with the menuentry for lfs, which is the same result as unplugging my main drive and booting to the external one.
When I select the entry. !EDIT- SEE BELOW!it starts boot and tells me it is unable to mount the kernel on (hd0,0).

EDIT: I misspoke, on boot from supergrub it tells me that

```
error: disk '/dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid of root partition>' not found.
```

here is the output of lsblk with main drive, external drive and supergrub usb plugged in

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    1 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    1   512M  0 part
└─sda2   8:2    1 465.3G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0    99M  0 part
├─sdb2   8:18   0   425M  0 part /mnt/lfs/boot
├─sdb3   8:19   0  27.4G  0 part /mnt/lfs
└─sdb4   8:20   0   2.8G  0 part
sdc      8:32   1  57.3G  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   1   148K  0 part
├─sdc2   8:34   1   2.8M  0 part
└─sdc3   8:35   1  16.6M  0 part
```

Please let me know if there is more information I can provide.

Thanks for your help and time!!

Comment: boot holds grub. if you point to boot in grub, you are just pointing it to itself. Please list your partitions by UUID and replace the UUID you currently have set with the correct UUID from sdb3. It's telling you it is incorrect because it probably is. this line in grub is likely the offender: `set root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/601dfc72-8481-40d6-bd42-1194dc574feb`